# Почему метод GET и DELETE являются идемпотентными?

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Я не понимаю, почему метод GET должен возвращать один и тот же результат? Например, на сервере изменили какой-то ресурс и потом, когда мы к нему обратимся, ответ от сервера будет другим. Почему тогда он идемпотентный?

Также я не понимаю, почему метод DELETE возвращает один и тот же результат. Допустим, первый раз мы удалили ресурс, но в следующий раз, если мы перейдем по той же ссылке, то должны получить ответ, что ресурс уже удален.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем я не права?

Comment: Важен не ответ сервера, а состояние. Если метод не изменяет состояние сервера он имподентный. P.S. в это нет смысла вникать, достаточно просто знать (хотя эти знания вряд ли пригодядтся)

Comment: Ответы здесь ни при чём. Идемпотентность здесь означает, что повторный запрос **не изменит состояние сервера**. Это верно и для GET-запросов (сервер просто отдаст ответ и не изменится), и для DELETE-запросов (невозможно удалить ресурс больше чем один раз)

Answer (score 4):

Для идемпотентности нужно рассматривать только изменение фактического внутреннего состояния сервера. Когда мы используем метод `GET` мы ничего им не меняем на сервере. когда мы используем метод `PUT` с каким-то индетификатором мы меняем только одну единственную запись, так же метод `DELETE` удаляет одну конкретную запись.

Можно представить например как список дел:

1. Купить кефир
2. Выгулять питомца
3. Сходить в кино

Независимо от того сколько раз подряд мы его прочтем он не изменится так как `GET` этот метод на чтение, он не добавляет в список ничего и ничего из него не убирает. Можно представить что у нас есть кнопка `получить список` и мы случайно нажали на нее 2 раза.

Теперь метод `PUT` например мы хотим купить не кефир а молоко, сколько бы раз мы не вызывали метод с изменением пункта 1 на `Купить молоко` по факту замена не приведет к новым эффектам, т.е. произойдет один (первый) раз, как замена слова в текстовом редакторе.

Что касается `DELETE` например мы выгуляли питомца таким образом мы удаляем пункт `2̶)̶ ̶В̶ы̶г̶у̶л̶я̶т̶ь̶ ̶п̶и̶т̶о̶м̶ц̶а̶` сколько бы раз мы его не удаляли у нас по прежнему будут пункты 1 и 3. Как и c `PUT` состояние на сервере изменится только 1 раз.

Что касается `POST` то мы можем добавить несколько одинаковых записей при каждой отсылке запроса, например если мы планируем купить 2 бутылки кефира нам нужно отправить запрос дважды (если это в сайт магазина то в корзине будет 2 кефира или столько сколько мы нажмем на кнопку `добавить`)

Что касается `PATCH` - cогласно документации он может быть идемпотентным и нет. В конечном счете идемпотентность зависит от конкретной реализации. `PATCH` является гораздо более общим по сравнению с `PUT`, по сути его можно использовать для управления ресурсами а не для изменения поля в таблице, например в `PATCH` могут переданы инструкции:

```
[
  { "op": "move", "from": "/biscuits", "path": "/cookies" }
  { "op": "remove", "path": "/foo" }
]
```

таким образом первый раз он отработает, а второй раз он нет (`biscuits` не будет найден так как он станет `cookies`)
и произойдет отказ (ошибка) - а это уже разные результаты выполнения.

Comment: Хорошо. Как я поняла, состояние сервера это что-то типа базы данных, к которой обращаешься только ты и никто изменения в нее не вносит, кроме тебя. Но как быть тогда с методом patch, почему он не идемпотентный? Ведь мы меняем в строке таблицы какое-то поле и сколько бы мы не меняли это поле, строка целиком должна остаться одной и той же от запроса к запросу. Подскажите, плиз, в чем ошибка моих рассуждений.

Comment: @Галина, я дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: Только метод patch используется для передачи инструкций на сервер?

Comment: @Галина смотря что считать инструкциями) в целом для каждого из методов есть своя область применения, хотя это не строго принципиально, разработчик может реализовать как он видит. однако по документации так https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods, впрочем это уже за рамками изначального вопроса.

Comment: Ну, я это спросила, потому что в основном всегда пишут, что эти методы выполняют действия над ресурсами. Поэтому когда вы написали про инструкции в методе patch, меня это немного запутало. Чем отличается действие над ресурсом от инструкции к ресурсу?

Comment: И я возможно не до конца понимаю понятие ресурса. Это строка в базе данных или статический файл? Что значит меняется состояние сервера? Меняется ресурс? Что понимается под побочным эффектом на сервере?   Мне просто сложно понимать абстрактные вещи.

Comment: @Галина да это как раз абстрактные вещи, ресурсом может быть файл, дирректория, база данных, таблица в базе данных и т.п. Пожалуйста, оформите свой вопрос отдельным вопросом(или вопросами), получите ответы, потому что об этом можно долго рассуждать но стековервлоу не приветсвует много комментариев лучше один вопрос - один ответ.  Если вам знакомо функциональное программирование то там хорошо объясняется что такое побочный эффект. Надеюсь я ответил на ваш первоначальный вопрос.

Comment: Ок, оформлю это в отдельные вопросы. Спасибо. Наверное, из-за непонимания этих понятий и возник этот вопрос.

Comment: @Галина, важно еще понимать зачем нужен ответ на этот вопрос, я точно знаю что многие не задаются этим вопросом, в отличие от Вас. Не скажу что практической пользы от этого вопроса нет, но это узкоспециализированная тема, далеко не покрывающая практическую работу с сервером - вершина айсберга.

Comment: Ну честно говоря, мне это надо, чтобы над контроллёром выбрать тот или иной метод (в виде аннотации). Например, я сомневаюсь, где надо ставить put, а где patch. Поэтому решила глубже разобраться в этой теме.

Comment: @Галина это зависит от задачи возможно, но в целом далеко не все методы всегда используются POST, GET, PUT, DELETE - часто достаточно чтобы создать полноценное API, PATCH не упоминается в заголовке вопроса. 
В книге Сергея Константинова. "API" есть такая цитата про PATCH:
__Избегайте частичных обновлений - такой подход часто практикуют для того, чтобы уменьшить объёмы запросов и ответов, плюс это позволяет дёшево реализовать совместное редактирование. Оба этих преимущества на самом деле являются мнимыми.__ Думаю этого будет достаточно чтобы определится, конечно может быть что нужен PATCH.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Думаю, для начала мне достаточно.